# Extract specific characters from a string

Tags: sql-server

I have a requirement where we have a field called address.  In this field, we can allow alphabets, numbers and some special characters.  Below is the list of those special characters.

I could think of a way is create a table storing ASCII of each allowed character and then compare each char of the string and getting only permitted characters.

Can anyone suggest a better way for the same?  Any help would be really appreciated.  Below is the list of allowed characters :

a-z, 0-9, A-Z, ':;@<>.&=()%/~-_!#$® (space)

Comment: You want to remove those non-allowed characters from the column?

Comment: the one's that i have mentioned should be allowed and anything else should be removed.  For e.g. if ? is there then that should be removed

Comment: This sounds more like a job for UI/Application code to do the validation and filtering, something like a regular expression would easily do it, why would you bother to pass down those invalid characters to the database level?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `LIKE` with a negative match `[^...]` in SQL, even it's better job for the front end. Here's an example:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (
    String      nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @Test
    VALUES  (N'123 Fake St'), (N'??? unknown street')


SELECT  String,
        CASE
            WHEN String LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9'':;@<>.&=()%/~-_!#$® ]%' THEN 'Has Invalid Character'
            ELSE 'Valid'
        END
FROM    @Test
```

P.S.: are you sure that an address with the copyright character is valid?